# Cannot assign SimpleLazyObject for CustomUser Model in django

Tags: python, html, css, django

everyone, I created a blogpost so whenever I want to add a new blogpost I get this error

```
ValueError at /pages/blog/new/
Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <CustomUser: exa@no.com>>": "Blog.doctor" must be a "Doctor" instance.
```

here is my views.py

```
class BlogCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Blog
    fields = ['title', 'categories', 'overview']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.doctor = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have a model called doctor, so assign the doctor from that class

```
  def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.doctor = Doctor.objects.get(doctor=self.request.user)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: how i wish i can hug you right now,you just saved my 3 days of debuging

Comment: thanks for the complement, if it answers please mark as answer